# \colorbox{color}{text} display issue with same math expressions but different syntax

Tags: color, amsmath, tcolorbox

My following LaTeX file in MikTeX' TeXworks editor on my Windows 8.1 is showing the `highlighted` content with different sizes when the highlighted content is inside quadratic formula but not when it's outside the quadratic formula - even though I'm using `fboxsep` in the preamble of the TeX file. I expected the third display below of the quadratic formula to be of the same size as of the second display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\text{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}}
\begin{document}
 This  \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b2- 4ac}}{2a}\) and \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\highlight{b2- 4ac}}}{2a}\) Vs.  \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}}{2a}\) is a test. Also a test: \( \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}\) vs \(\sqrt{\highlight{b2- 4ac}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Once you're in the `\colorbox`, LaTeX forgets that you were in math mode and it forgets the type of font you were using.  In math mode there are four different sizes:

```
\displaystyle
\textstyle
\scriptstyle
\scriptscriptstyle
```

If you rewrite you third equation as

```
\(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(\scriptstyle b2- 4ac\)}}}{2a}\)
```

then you'll get the same size script as in the two early versions.

But better than having to guess the font size (and there's more going on when you try to use super/subscripts within the square root), I suggest playing with `hf-tikz` as in

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\text{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}}

\tikzset{set fill color=yellow,
         set border color=yellow,
         disable rounded corners=true}

\begin{document}

 This \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}\) 
  and \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\highlight{b^2- 4ac}}}{2a}\) 
  Vs. $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{%%
    \tikzmarkin{A}(0,1ex)(0,-0pt)
      b^2- 4ac
    \tikzmarkend{A}}}{2a}\) is a test. Also a test: 
      \( \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}\) 
  vs  \(\sqrt{\highlight{b2- 4ac}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. You stated: `Once you're in the \colorbox, LaTeX forgets that you were in math mode and it forgets the type of font you were using` But my `newCommand` for highlight is also using `\colorbox` and it's displaying the highlighted portion in the second equation same size as in first. Does this have anything to do with using `colorbox` with `newcommand`? Moreover, using `hf-tikz` makes the display of third equation in your post the right size but the the display of second equation looks larger. Any comments/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with `tcolorbox` and its `\tcbhighmath` command, wrapped in `\highlightnew:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\text{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}}

\newcommand{\highlightnew}[2][]{\tcbhighmath[size=minimal,colframe=yellow,colback=yellow,#1]{#2}}
\begin{document}
 This  \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b2- 4ac}}{2a}\) and \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\highlight{b2- 4ac}}}{2a}\) Vs.  \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}}{2a}\) is a test. Also a test: \( \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}\) vs \(\sqrt{\highlight{b2- 4ac}}\)

 This  \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b2- 4ac}}{2a}\) and \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\highlightnew{b2- 4ac}}}{2a}\) Vs.  \(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}}{2a}\) is a test. Also a test: \( \sqrt{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b2- 4ac\)}}\) vs \(\sqrt{\highlightnew{b2- 4ac}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]